# Problems working with the ACL of a folder in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: acl, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've created an object inside a folder in Google Cloud Storage whith the following OptionsBuilder object:

```
GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
  .setBucket("bucket")
  .setKey("folder/obj.csv")
  .setMimeType("text/csv");
```

Making the next structure:

bucket >> folder >> obj.csv

When I run the gsutil command to get ACL for "bucket" and "obj.csv" works fine, however when I execute it for "folder" throws this exception:
GSResponseError: status=404, code=NoSuchKey, reason=Not Found.

The exactly command I run is: gsutil getacl gs://bucket/folder/ > acl.txt

How I can get and set permissions on a folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only retrieve the ACL of an object or a bucket. There is no such thing as a "folder" in GCS, so you can't set or get the ACL of a folder. I suggest you read the [Concepts and Terminology](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide#concepts) section of the developer guide carefully. In particular, the section on object names:

> Object names
>
> An object name is just metadata to Google Cloud Storage. Object names
>   can contain any combination of Unicode characters (UTF-8 encoded) less
>   than 1024 bytes in length. A common character to include in file names
>   is a slash (/). By using slashes in an object name, you can make
>   objects appear as though they're stored in a hierarchical structure.
>   For example, you could name one object /europe/france/paris.jpg and
>   another object /europe/france/cannes.jpg. When you list these objects
>   they appear to be in a hierarchical directory structure based on
>   location; however, Google Cloud Storage sees the objects as
>   independent objects with no hierarchical relationship whatsoever.